# Yii2 ActiveForm - dropDownList make template for {input}

Tags: php, yii2

Inside **option** tag I need to add **span** tag, and the code should look like this:

```
<option><span class=flag></span></option>
```

I also need to put flag name as a span second class parameter. The thing I need to assign is **currency_code**. This is the current code:

```
<?php
    echo $form->field($model, 'currency', [
            'template' => '<label>{label}</label>{input}{hint}'
        ])
        ->dropDownList([NULL => ''] + ArrayHelper::map(app\models\Currency::find()->all(), 'currency_code', 'currency_code'), ['role' => 'currency_code'])->hint('Select preferred currency.')
    ?>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will help you

```
$listData=['1'=>'value1', '2'=>'value2', '3'=>'value3'];

$options=
[
'1' => ['disabled' => true],
'2' => ['label' => 'some other label2'],
'3' => ['class' => 'someclass'],
];

echo $form->field($model, 'attribute')->dropDownList(
$listData,
['prompt'=>'Select...', 'options'=>$options]);
```

which will produce some select html code like this

```
<select name="Model[attribute]" class="form-control" id="model-attribute">
<option value="">Select...</option>
<option disabled="" selected="" value="1">value1</option>
<option label="some other label2" value="2">value2</option>
<option value="3" class="someclass">value3</option>
</select>
```

so with the options you can set the parameters of the listdata (listitems)

Edit:

```
 $listData=ArrayHelper::map(Organizer::find()->all(), 'id', 'name');
$listData=['1'=>'<span>some html added</span>', '2'=>'value2', '3'=>'value3'];
$options=
[
'1' => ['disabled' => true],
'2' => ['label' => 'some other label2'],
'3' => ['class' => 'someclass', 'value'=>'<span>some html added</span>'],
];

echo $form->field($model, 'organizer_id')->dropDownList(
                                $listData,
                                ['prompt'=>'Select...','encode'=>true,'options'=>$options]);
```

would return

```
<select name="Poll[organizer_id]" class="form-control" id="poll-organizer_id">
<option value="">Select...</option>
<option disabled="" selected="" value="1">&lt;span&gt;some html added&lt;/span&gt;</option>
<option label="some other label2" value="2">value2</option>
<option value="3" class="someclass">value3</option>
</select>
```

sadly if i disable the encoding only the text will be displayed, and the html is gone...
But i guess there must be a way to do this.

Edit2:
I found out why it didn't work in option no other tags are allowed (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option). 
So my first solution was correct. You should be able to add your flag icons to the option by background-image.

Comment: This is not even close to what I need :/. I need to put span tag inside options tag, add assigned class to the span with value from ArrayHelper

Comment: yeah i also just have seen this, was too fast with reading sry.
i guess then your only option is to extend BaseHtml::dropDownList or extend static::renderSelectOptions($selection, $items, $options); because this is the functions which returns the options. I haven't found a possibility to change the "text" in that function by some option.

Comment: just added someting but still not the correct solution.

Comment: added edit2 i answered why the tags were not displayed correctly in the option tag.

Comment: Cool :). Thanks for helping me :)